# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have many DAO that defined like this:

> IxxxDAO

I am using **MyBatis** and here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = {
        "com.dounets.app.adm.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.bil.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.common.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.dd.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.dm.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.dmv2.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.pim.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.report.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.tat.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.pi.ui.**.dao",
        "com.dounets.app.process.dao",
})
public class MyBatisConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource, ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(applicationContext.getResources("classpath:mapper/*.xml"));
        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

If I comment out some packages, It worked fine. But If I scan all packages, It throws exception:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'
```

Full error:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': :
 Error creating bean with name 'IAdmCmtUsrLikeDAO' defined in file [IAdmCmtUsrLikeDAO.class]:
```

I tried to scan each package, And all of packages are fine.

Let see my sample IxxxDAO:

```
public interface IAdmCmtUsrLikeDAO extends IApplicationDAO {

    int delete(AdmCmtUsrLikeVOKey data) throws SQLException;

    int insert(AdmCmtUsrLikeVO data) throws SQLException;

    List<AdmCmtUsrLikeVO> select() throws SQLException;

    AdmCmtUsrLikeVO select(AdmCmtUsrLikeVOKey data) throws SQLException;

    int update(AdmCmtUsrLikeVO data) throws SQLException;

    int update(HashMap<String, Object> data) throws SQLException;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this exception look for "Injection of autowired dependencies failed" somewhere in the logs. That should be your problem. I had the same error too.

More info:
https://bethelwhite.wordpress.com/2015/10/16/mybatis-spring-trouble-is-there-an-unresolvable-circular-reference-may-be-a-misleading-message/